# Exposed Romex cable on garage ceiling without conduit protection

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage, conduit

I am working on an old house.  The garage ceiling (attic floor) has exposed beams (ie. it doesn't have sheetrock on the underside that provides for a finished ceiling).  The power to the garage door opener and to the outlets on the other side of the garage go through a romex that is stapled to one of the beams.  It goes into an outlet for the garage opener to connect to and then continues to the other side of the garage and hides inside the wall.  Do I need to insert that romex inside a conduit sleeve?  Or, is it okay being "exposed" like that?  The ceiling is about 8.5 ft height so it is not within reach for a typical person.  Also, the outlet box is nailed to the beam and has a typical cover but it is also "exposed".  It is a metal box  but it is grounded.

Comment: Does the Romex run parallel or perpendicular to the joists?  But more importantly, I would want drywall or some kind of fire protection on that garage ceiling!

Comment: Yes, the Romex is running parallel (along the side) of just one beam from one side of the garage to the other (one car garage).  Point is well taken on fire protection.

Comment: You're good as far as NEC goes.

Comment: I have never seen any AHJ have a problem with romex in that way even if it was drilled through. Where is the subject of damage. You drill out your basement  all fine. Now when you are coming down a stud you are putting wire in harms way wirers need protection sleeve or change or to emt.

Answer (score 4):

Stapled to the sides of joists, or through drilled holes, is fine in this installation.

Comment: All day long.  May be if coming down a stud .